# Double encoded get parameters values

Tags: html, limesurvey

I have this scenario:

[Link Here](http://polls.schwarzkopf-stiftung.de/index.php/257158?Region=Berlin/Brandenburg&SchoolName=Test001&CourseID=2982&CourseDate=30.01.2018&SchoolType=Juhu&NumberStudents=2&City=Goa&Country=French%20Southern%20Territories&PostCode=403507&CourseType=eu%20crash%20course%C3%B6)

Above mentioned is the URL I'm generating on my site by using urlencode() for the values of the get parameters. When the user clicks on the link from my site, it's redirected to the survey form (Lime survey). The values in the form are added without URL decode.

What I have noticed is that the browser encodes the values again in the URL. The above-mentioned URL it encodes in the following way:

[Link Here](https://polls.schwarzkopf-stiftung.de/index.php/257158?Region=Berlin/Brandenburg&SchoolName=Test001&CourseID=2982&CourseDate=30.01.2018&SchoolType=Juhu&NumberStudents=2&City=Goa&Country=French%20Southern%20Territories&PostCode=403507&CourseType=eu%20crash%20course%25C3%25B6)

If you noticed, the last value `eu+crash+course%C3%B6` is encoded by the browser to `eu+crash+course%25C3%25B6`

How can I restrict the browser from doing that?